# Workflow with pipeline

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, pipeline

I have following powershell script:

```
function Testing
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (                
        [int]$MaxRetrycount = 3,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [String]$Definition
    )   
    return $MaxRetrycount
}

workflow Test-Workflow
{
    $PSComputerName

    $data = 'abc','xyz'
    $data | Testing -MaxRetrycount 2 -Definition
    $JobName
}

Test-Workflow
```

But execution of this script giving me error like

> *The 'Testing' activity is not supported in a workflow pipeline.*

Did I make any mistake in calling function with command pipeline from workflow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with workflows. You are just calling the Testing function wrong. Try testing your function outside of a workflow.

Comment: @Dangph thanks for suggestion, I tried it working outside but not working inside workflow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, using pipeline input doesn't work but it does work if you invoke the function not using pipeline input:

```
function Test-Function
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (                
        [int]$MaxRetrycount = 3,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [String]$Definition
    )   
    return $MaxRetrycount
}

workflow Test-Workflow
{
        $PSComputerName

        $data = 'abc','xyz'
        foreach ($d in $data) {
            Test-Function -MaxRetrycount 2 -Definition $d
        }
        $JobName
}

Test-Workflow
```

Outputs:

```
Test-Workflow
2
Job37
```

Comment: Thanks @KeithHill for your help, but I want to pass "data" array elements one by one via command pipeline like calling "Test-Function" function with -Defination 'abc' and second time with 'xyz'. Do you know how can I do that inside workflow function?

Comment: You can use a foreach construct to iterate.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @KeithHill your answer is useful but my problem in this approach is related retrieving data from remote session in powershell remoting.

Comment: One trick that helped me to grok the pushups that PowerShell is doing behind the scenes is to examine the generated workflow XAML definition e.g. `(Get-Command Test-Workflow).XamlDefinition`.  IMO it helps to see how PowerShell is taking your script and converting it to XAML.